# If $a^6-b^6=15$ and $a^3+b^3=15$ find the value of $a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a^6-b^6=15$ and $a^3+b^3=15$ find the value of $a$. This is a question in a maths test that I need help with for revision. why?

Comment: Hint: $a^6 - b^6 = (a^3+b^3)(a^3-b^3)$.

Comment: Here is meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/… .for formatting.

Answer (score 8):

Write ${ a }^{ 6 }-{ b }^{ 6 }=15$ as $$\left( { a }^{ 3 }-{ b }^{ 3 } \right) \left( { a }^{ 3 }+{ b }^{ 3 } \right) =15$$  from this we get since (${ a }^{ 3 }+{ b }^{ 3 }=15$ )
$${ a }^{ 3 }-{ b }^{ 3 }=1$$ $$ \begin{cases} { a }^{ 3 }-{ b }^{ 3 }=1 \\ { a }^{ 3 }{ +b }^{ 3 }=15 \end{cases}\Rightarrow 2{ a }^{ 3 }=16\Rightarrow \quad a=2$$

Answer (score 2):

$a^6-b^6= (a^3+b^3)(a^3-b^3)$. As it is given that $a^3+b^3 =15$, it implies that $a^3-b^3 = 1$. Now as we of two equations, solve for $a^3$ and $b^3$. Adding the two equations $a^3+b^3 =15$ and $a^3-b^3 =1$ we get $2a^3 =16$ which implies $a=2$.

So value of $a$ is 2.

Answer (score 1):

from $a^6-b^6=15,\ a^3+b^3=15$ and the above mentioned hint, we have $a^3-b^3=1$. Now, considering $a^3+b^3=15$ and $a^3-b^3=1$, we obtain $a^3=8\rightarrow a=2$ and $b^3=7$.